# Generating function for $15, 66,189,420,795,\dots$

Tags: sequences-and-series, generating-functions

I am to derive the formula for $15,66,189,420, 795,\dots$

I have the common pattern as $3m(2n+1)$ where $n$ and $m$ are integers. For example,

$66=3\cdot2\cdot(2\cdot5+1)$

Will this end up in me deriving the correct formula or is there another pattern? Also could someone help me with the next step.

Comment: Could be anything, where do the numbers come from ?

Comment: That's what the question asks,not sure what is meant by where the numbers are from

Comment: It might be a degree-$3$ polynomial such as $6n^3+9n$

Comment: @Henry You are probably right! (See my answer below)

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be on the right track. The numbers are

$$3\cdot 1\cdot 5$$

$$3\cdot 2\cdot 11$$

$$3\cdot 3\cdot 21$$

$$3\cdot 4\cdot 35$$

$$3\cdot 5\cdot 53$$

The differences in the last column are $6,10,14,18$ , forming an arithmetic progression. So, we have $$a_n=3n\cdot (2n^2+3)=6n^3+9n$$

Comment: Well played....

Comment: Thank you, Evariste! The main work was done by the OP, though.

Comment: Thank you so much, after this i just used scaling and differentiate and other methods to derive a function correct?